PHP preg_match merge two p tags into one
I want to merge paragraph one and paragraph two into one paragraph using preg_match,
$html = "<p>Title:</p><p>Second paragraph</p><p>Third paragraph</p>"

expected results
$html = "<p>Title:Second paragraph</p><p>Third paragraph</p>"


Just remove the first </p><p>.

Have you tried using an HTML parser?

If we put aside why you'd want to do this, here's a solution:
$merged = preg_replace('~^(.*?)\<\/p\>\<p\>(.*)$~i', '$1$2', $html);

This will find the first part of the string (before the </p></p>) and the second part, after the (first) tags, and replace it with the first match and second match, effectively removing only the first </p><p> match.

There is no reason to match the substrings which will be retained. Regex is not needed for the unchallenging [mcve].
